# Is this a bug of SymPy?

Tags: sympy

Why do we have a strange result with integration of expression by SymPy.

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> from sympy import __version__
>>> __version__
'1.8'
>>> x = Symbol('x')
>>> f = (x**2 - Rational(1, 4))**2 * sqrt(1 - x**2); f
sqrt(1 - x**2)*(x**2 - 1/4)**2
>>> integrate(f, (x, -1, 1))
0
```

The integrand is strictly positive, this result is wrong.
However, dividing the interval (x, -1, 1) into (x, -1, 0) and (x, 0, 1), we have the correct.

```
>>> integrate(f, (x, -1, 0))
pi/64
>>> integrate(f, (x, 0, 1))
pi/64
```

Expanding the integrand, the result is also correct.

```
>>> g = f.expand(); g
x**4*sqrt(1 - x**2) - x**2*sqrt(1 - x**2)/2 + sqrt(1 - x**2)/16
>>> integrate(g, (x, -1, 1))
pi/32
```

This strange phenomenon has occurred since version 1.5 of SymPy.

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> from sympy import __version__
>>> __version__
'1.4'
>>> x = Symbol('x')
>>> f = (x**2 - Rational(1, 4))**2 * sqrt(1 - x**2); f
sqrt(1 - x**2)*(x**2 - 1/4)**2
>>> integrate(f, (x, -1, 1))
pi/32
```

Is this a bug?

Comment: Yes, it is a bug. Please open an issue with sympy on github.

Answer (score 0):

Discussion is continued to the following.

https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/22033?fbclid=IwAR3oPgk-sLipSDWe7lsRmqG_hpw0fEEgED5XU5K96IKDi-UnVyOzqQqjSYY

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the code of integrate function, but I understand as follows.
The primitive function of `f = (x**2 - Rational(1,4))**2 * sqrt(1 - x**2)` is this.

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> x = Symbol('x')
>>> f = (x**2 - Rational(1,4))**2 * sqrt(1 - x**2)
>>> F = integrate(f).simplify(); F
Piecewise((-x**3*(1 - x**2)**(3/2)/6 + x*sqrt(1 - x**2)/32 + asin(x)/32, (x > -1) & (x < 1)))
>>> X = np.linspace(-1, 1, 1000)
>>> Y = np.vectorize(Lambda(x, F))(X)
>>> plt.plot(X, Y)
>>> plt.show()
```

This is correct.
However, in the definite integral with respect to a real number, another expression `fr` of `xr` is used as folows.

```
>>> xr = Symbol('xr', real=True)
>>> fr = (xr**2 - Rational(1,4))**2 * sqrt(1 - xr**2)
>>> Fr = integrate(fr).simplify()
>>> Fr
Piecewise((xr**4*sqrt(1 - xr**2)*Abs(xr)/6 - xr**2*sqrt(1 - xr**2)*Abs(xr)/6 + sqrt(1 - xr**2)*Abs(xr)/32 - asin(sqrt(1 - xr**2))/32, (xr > -1) & (xr < 1) & Ne(xr, 0)))
>>> Yr = np.vectorize(Lambda(xr, Fr))(X)
>>> plt.plot(X, Yr)
>>> plt.show()
```

This is incorrect.
I think that integration by substitution with `y = x**2` is used inadequetly like this..

```
>>> y = Symbol('y')
>>> g = (y - Rational(1,4))**2 * sqrt(1 - y)/2/sqrt(y)
>>> G = integrate(g).simplify(); G
Piecewise((y**(5/2)*sqrt(1 - y)/6 - y**(3/2)*sqrt(1 - y)/6 + sqrt(y)*sqrt(1 - y)/32 - asin(sqrt(1 - y))/32, (y <= 1) & (y > 0)))
>>> Gr = G.subs(y, x**2).simplify(); Gr
Piecewise((sqrt(1 - x**2)*(x**2)**(5/2)/6 - sqrt(1 - x**2)*(x**2)**(3/2)/6 + sqrt(1 - x**2)*sqrt(x**2)/32 - asin(sqrt(1 - x**2))/32, (x > -1) & (x < 1) & Ne(x, 0)))
>>> Z = np.vectorize(Lambda(x, Gr))(X)
>>> plt.plot(X, Z)
>>> plt.show()
```

This function is same as `Fr` above.

However, I don't know why the well known integration by substitution with `x = sin(t)` isn't used.

```
>>> t = Symbol('t')
>>> h = (sin(t)**2 - Rational(1,4))**2 * cos(t)**2
>>> H = integrate(h).simplify()
>>> H = integrate(h)
>>> H
t*sin(t)**6/16 + 3*t*sin(t)**4*cos(t)**2/16 - t*sin(t)**4/16 + 3*t*sin(t)**2*cos(t)**4/16 - t*sin(t)**2*cos(t)**2/8 + t*sin(t)**2/32 + t*cos(t)**6/16 - t*cos(t)**4/16 + t*cos(t)**2/32 + sin(t)**5*cos(t)/16 - sin(t)**3*cos(t)**3/6 - sin(t)**3*cos(t)/16 - sin(t)*cos(t)**5/16 + sin(t)*cos(t)**3/16 + sin(t)*cos(t)/32
>>> H1 = H.subs(t, asin(x)).simplify(); H1
x**5*sqrt(1 - x**2)/6 - x**3*sqrt(1 - x**2)/6 + x*sqrt(1 - x**2)/32 + asin(x)/32
```

This is same as primitive function `F` of `f` above and has another expression.

```
>>> H2 = H.simplify().subs(t, asin(x)); H2
sin(6*asin(x))/192 + asin(x)/32
>>> plt.show()
```

Using this we are able to have the following correct definite integral of `f` over [-1, 1].

```
>>> H2.subs(x, 1) - H2.subs(x, -1)
pi/32
```